# OpenSSH Server won't start on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, openssh

I have followed [this example](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/1487/setting-up-a-sftp-server-on-windows) to setup an SFTP server on Windows 7.

I have done this before on XP and it worked a treat, and the process seemed to go OK on Windows 7 but now I can't get the OpenSSH Server service to start.

Do I need to do something extra on Windows 7? I followed the tutorial to the letter.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to start the service?  Is there anything reported in the Event Logs after it fails to start?  Which OpenSSH server are you using?  Does it require Cygwin to also be installed? If so, have you installed it? :) Have you checked/tested Firewall and UAC settings?

Comment: When I try to start the service it appears to start for a second, then stops again. Event log tells me that `The OpenSSH Server service hung on starting.` I am using the OpenSSH server linked in the article. I have CYGWin Bash Shell installed, is this what you mean? Thanks

Comment: The OpenSSH for Windows linked in the article is from 2004.  LONG before Windows 7 and it's new security measures existed.  You may want to find a more current alternative if adjusting the Firewall and/or UAC and/or file permissions doesn't help any.

Comment: Thanks, the error in the event log I mentioned isn't the main I am getting, apologies it is `The OpenSSH Server service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 6 time(s).`. I didn't notice the age of the article, do you know if the same basic principles apply setting modern SSH equivalents to host an SFTP site?